# Segregating Python3 Dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a directory named "modules" and installed the redis library under it.

```
pip install redis -t modules
```

**Directory Structure**

```
 - lamda_function.py
 - modules
   - redis
```

I imported the module in lambda_function.py using the below statement

```
import redis
```

Below is the error that I am seeing

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'redis'

This works fine if I install redis outside "modules" directory. However , is there a way to reference redis from inside modules directory?

Comment: Can you trying importing the library like this: `import modules.redis`?

Comment: sure , will try. Thanks.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Add an `__init__.py` in your module directory. Afterwards `import modules.redis` should work.

Comment: Sure , Thank you!

Comment: should __init__.py have any data?